# How can I extract the text from a div tag with style attribute set as "display: none;" through selenium

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, display

My html looks like this:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-7">
        <ul class="breadcrumb">
            <li id="get_data"><a href="#">Get data</a></li>
            <li id="sampling_task"><a href="#">Sampling</a></li>
            <li id="confirm_task"><a href="#">Confirmation</a></li>
        </ul>

        <div class="container-fluid">
            <form action="#" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" role="form" class="form-horizontal">
                {% csrf_token %}
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="id_fileA" class="col-sm-3 control-label" style="text-align: left">
                        Select dataset A<span class='required_label'>*</span>
                    </label>
                    <div class="col-sm-9">
                        {{ form.fileA|attr:"class:form-control" }}
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group"></div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="id_fileB" class="col-sm-3 control-label" style="text-align: left">
                        Select dataset B<span class='required_label'>*</span>
                    </label>
                    <div class="col-sm-9">
                        {{ form.fileB|attr:"class:form-control" }}
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group"></div>

                <div class="form-group" id="sample_btn" style="display: none">
                    <label class="col-sm-3 control-label"></label>
                    <div class="col-sm-9">
                        <input type="button" name="theButton" id="sample-step" value="Start Sampling" class="btn btn-success btn-large disabled" style="border-radius: 5px;">
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-sm-9 col-sm-offset-3" id="sample_msg" style="display: none;">
                        <p id="sample_text" style="font-size: medium">
                            Some ABCD message
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-sm-9 col-sm-offset-3" id="get_sample_confirm_msg" style="display: none;">
                        <p>
                        <input type="button" style="height: 40px; width: 140px; border-radius: 5px" name="YesButton" id="accept-step" value="Accept & Continue" class="btn btn-success disabled">
                        <input type="button" style="height: 40px; width: 140px; border-radius: 5px" name="NoButton" id="cancel-step" value="Cancel Sampling" class="btn btn-danger disabled">
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-5">
    </div>
</div>
```

The backend is a javascript and on button click, it do processing and if something fails the javascript code update the message.

```
var error = "<div class='alert alert-danger'><p>We encountered an error while sampling: <br /><strong>Sampling failed!!</strong></p>"; error += "<p>Please <a href='mailto:abcd@gmail.com'>contact us</a> if this error persists.</p>";
error += "</div>";
$('#sample_msg').html(error);
```

Now, in my selenium code if I do this:

```
sample_msg = self.driver.find_element_by_id('sample_msg')
```

I get an empty list result. What I want is to do is read the error in the "sample_msg" class if any and I have tried few things but its not working out. Help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Can you elaborate a little about *"I get an empty list result"*? `find_element_by_id()` usually returns WebElement or `NoSuchElementException` in case no element found, but it never returns empty/non-empty list

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get access to hidden text you might need to use below code:

```
sample_msg = self.driver.find_element_by_id('sample_msg').get_attribute('textContent').strip()
```

Note that `text` property allows to get text from visible elements only

Answer (score 0):

As you are trying to extract the error message **Some ABCD message** it is contained within a `<p>` tag which have parent `<div>` tag with *style* attribute set as **display: none;**. So to extract the text you can use the following code block :

```
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='form-group']/div[@id='sample_msg']")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].removeAttribute('style')", element)
print(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='form-group']/div[@id='sample_msg']/p").get_attribute("innerHTML"))
```

Answer (score 0):

So, you have to wait for sometime after clicking the button and once some message appears then you need to extract that message.
Try below:-

WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(webDriver, timeoutInSeconds);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id));
or

wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id));
to be precise.

See also:

[org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html) for similar shortcuts for various wait scenarios.
[org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/WebDriverWait.html) for its various constructors.

You can check the python syntax also on the above links.